# Shouldn't bounty be returned if no answers suggested?

Tags: support, status-completed, bounty

I offered a 50 point bounty to my question at [Is ANZLIC Metadata supported using the new approach of ArcGIS 10.x?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6013/anzlic-metadata-in-arcgis-10) but still received no answers and the bounty seems to have been forfeited.

In the case above shouldn't my bounty be returned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not how the bounty works.

[Why aren't bounties refunded if they are not awarded?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56298/why-arent-bounties-refunded-if-they-are-not-awarded)

The comment on this question sums it up, I think.
[Return bounty to questions that get no answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59931/return-bounty-to-questions-that-get-no-answers)

> A bounty is paying for 7 days of
>   increased exposure, you're not paying
>   the people who answer it. They just
>   get a winning if they do answer within
>   the period. It's also never going to
>   be a guarantee of an answer.

---

Also see [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) for more details about how bounties work.

Answer (score 3):

See https://gis.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty

> In any case, you will *always* give up the amount of reputation specified in the bounty, so if you start a bounty, be sure to follow up and award your bounty to the best answer!